# ternary statement not testing value as expected

Tags: php

How could I turn this if-statement into a ternary statement?

```
if ( !empty($vendor_address_row['address2'])){
    $address_obj['address2'] = $vendor_address_row['address2'];
    }else{
    $address_obj['address2'] = '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>';    
    }
```

I have trie

`$vendor_address_row['address2'] ? $address_obj['address2'] = '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>' : $address_obj['address2'] = '';`

and

`!empty($vendor_address_row['address2']) ? $address_obj['address2'] = '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>' : $address_obj['address2'] = '';`

Neither work. And there is probably a shorter way to do it besides. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can say that your title ("_ternary statement not testing value properly_") is incorrect: the one that tests that incorrectly is not the statement, you are. You are not using comparison, but assignment - and assignment gives true-ish value whenever new value is true-ish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether `$vendor_address_row['address2']` is always defined or not.

If it is (and version >= 5.3):

```
$address_obj['address2'] = $vendor_address_row['address2'] ?: '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>';
```

Or (version < 5.3):

```
$address_obj['address2'] = $vendor_address_row['address2'] ? $vendor_address_row['address2'] : '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>';
```

It it isn't:

```
$address_obj['address2'] = !empty($vendor_address_row['address2']) ? $vendor_address_row['address2'] : '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>';
```

You can reverse the operands to get rid of the `!empty()` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

this should be:

```
echo $address_obj['address2'] = !empty($vendor_address_row['address2']) ? $vendor_address_row['address2'] : ('<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>');
```

or to save it to a variable:

```
$address_obj['address2'] = !empty($vendor_address_row['address2']) ? $vendor_address_row['address2'] : ('<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$address_obj['address2'] = empty($vendor_address_row['address2']) ? '<tr><td colspan="1">'.$address_row['address2'].'</td></tr>' : $vendor_address_row['address2'] ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm a bit baffled by how it works though. if it the `empty()` test evaluates to false, how come it does not perform the task on the right side of the colon? I would think that should be done when the value `empty()` tests evaluates to true.

Comment: And after the `:` you go set it to $vendor_address_row['address2'] instead of an empty string. Why did you go this route? Thanks again.

Comment: The question was `How could I turn this if-statement into a ternary statement?` all i did was to follow the control of your if statement. There is no place in your if statement where empty string was set